# Static HTML written by meteor js? To embed in an <iframe>

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, static, meteor

Disclaimer - I am very new to making web apps, I just went through a few meteor js tutorials over the weekend, it's pretty cool.

I have this project I want to make, which involves embedding tabular data into websites. I want to do this with a iFrame.

I can see how this could be done with meteor, route to a template to render out the html I want, but I'm concerned with performance. Having the whole app load up to just display a few lines of html seems excessive, it certainly doesn't need all the javascript.

The html can be a static file, only changing when the web app user saves a change, it doesn't have to dynamically load every-time somebody sees the embed.

So what I'm really asking is, how can I use meteor js to write a static html file?

Comment: I think you should test before and see if actually works, then be care about the performance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is server side rendering (SSR), because you are intending to serve html directly from your meteor server.

Meteor does not support SSR, yet.

While I haven't myself tried to get SSR working in meteor, [Arunoda has](https://meteorhacks.com/server-side-rendering.html), ableit some rather severe limitations. Basically you cannot have much reactivity there. This is probably due to the use of fibers on the server. But you said you do not need reactivity anyway in your iframes, so that should not stop you.

You can combine Arunoda's solution with [Iron Router's server routes](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#server-routing).

Enable the SSR package:

```
meteor add meteorhacks:ssr
```

Put your template into the private directory:

```
<!-- private/embed.html -->
<template name="embed">
  <ul>
  {{#each posts}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

On the server, compile it with:

```
SSR.compileTemplate('embed', Assets.getText('embed.html'));
```

And declare your template manager:

```
// server/embed.js
Template.posts.getPosts = function(category) {
  return Posts.find({category: category}, {limit: 20});
}
```

And then add a server-route as follows:

```
Router.route('/embed/:owner', function () {
  var html = SSR.render('embed', {owner: this.params.owner});
  this.response.end(html);
}, {where: 'server'});
```

Now you just need to point your iframe to `http://localhost:3000/embed/myusername`.

At this stage I would not recommend using meteor in this way, but instead create a simple backend that connects to [DDP](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/DDP_Clients) or mongo directly and renders your iframe's html.